# How to understand $(\pm*d*\alpha) dV = \pm d(*\alpha)$ in Ricci flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Picture below is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow.

First, I don't know why
$$
(\pm*d*\alpha) dV = \pm d(*\alpha),
$$
in fact, I don't know what is $*\alpha$ and $d*\alpha$. In my opinion, $*$ should be linear combination of tensor times with contraction and switch the type. Therefore, in general, we use denotation as $1*A, A*B$ where  $A,B$ are tensor. But in $d*\alpha$, $d$ is an operator. Besides, $*\alpha$ is harder to understand.

Second, since $\delta(T)=- tr _{12} (\nabla T)$, I have
$$
\delta(f\alpha) = -g^{ij} \nabla_{\partial_i} (f\alpha)(\partial_j)
=
-g^{ij}\partial _i [f\alpha(\partial_j)] +g^{ij}f\alpha(\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j)
=
f(\delta \alpha) - g^{ij} \alpha(\partial_j) df(\partial_i)
=
f(\delta \alpha) - \langle df, \alpha\rangle 
$$
where $\alpha$ is 1-form. I always use to calculate in a local coordinate, seeemly, it makes thing becomes complex. How should I practice my calculation better ?

> [image]

Comment: It's the [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator).  Topping is using the $\ast$ notation to refer to two completely different things: sometimes he uses $\ast$ as in $A \ast B$ to refer to a sort of contraction, but other times he means the Hodge star operator.